# Getting an unauthorized_scope_error on an existing application with r_liteprofile

Tags: linkedin-api

We followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq#what-permissions-do-i-have-access-to

> All developer applications created on the LinkedIn Developer Portal
>   after January 14, 2019 have access to the LinkedIn v2 API by default.
>   Alternatively, if your developer application has made a successful
>   LinkedIn v1 API request from September 1, 2018 to December 17, 2018,
>   your developer application has immediate access to the v2 API.

We also meet the criteria here regarding successful API requests between that time period.

We made the switch shortly before the holidays(as soon as they sent the announcement) and since the last week, we've started seeing this for new signups:

```
unauthorized_scope_error | Scope "r_liteprofile" is not authorized for your application
```

Should we revert back to r_basicprofile for now?

This is for "Sign in with Linkedin".

This is the GET request: `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Flinkedin%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=r_liteprofile+r_emailaddress&state=XXXX`

This is the response redirect: `http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback?error=unauthorized_scope_error&error_description=Scope+%26quot%3Br_liteprofile%26quot%3B+is+not+authorized+for+your+application&state=XXXX`

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I was running into this today, and the step I was missing was I needed to add the "Sign In with LinkedIn" product to my app.

The terminology here is quite strange, but the screenshots help. You need to visit the "products" page on the developer portal (url like: [https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/[your](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/%5Byour) app id]/products)

[image: select linkedin app product]

After you do this and your request is approved (took <5 min for me) then the "OAuth 2.0 scopes" listed under the "Auth" tab will be expanded to include "r_emailaddress" and "r_liteprofile".